# How to save list of Objects in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I have a shopping cart that I want to save in local storage. I have saved items that are not inside an object but I couldn't figure out how to save a list of objects. I think it's not that hard but I couldn't find out the issue and I am actually new in programming so forgive me if my question was dumb. the code below will explain more.

//HTML Code//

```
<div class="added-product">
              <div class="each-cart-row">
                 <img class="image" src="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg">
                 <h4 class="title">T-shirt</h4>
                 <span class="price">$19.99</span>
                 <h3>1</h3>
                 <button class="removebtn">remove</button>
              </div>
              <div class="each-cart-row">
                 <img class="image" src="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg">
                 <h4 class="title">shirt</h4>
                 <span class="price">$14.99</span>
                 <h3>1</h3>
                 <button class="removebtn">remove</button>
              </div>
             </div>
```

//This is my first try//

```
var listitem = document.querySelector('.each-cart-row').textContent;
  localStorage.setItem('layoutlist', listitem);
  console.log(localStorage);
```

[and i got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mTLf.png)

//then i tried this code//

```
var listitem = document.querySelectorAll('.each-cart-row').textContent;
    for(var i = 0; i < listitem.length; i++){
        var title = listitem[i];
        localStorage.setItem('layoutlist', title);
            console.log(localStorage);   
     }
```

[and i got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsFN1.png)

//and lastly I used JSON //

```
var listitem = document.querySelectorAll('.each-cart-row');
       var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(listitem);
        localStorage.setItem('layoutlist', jsonstr);
            console.log(localStorage);
```

[and I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvt4k.png)

Comment: What exactly you want to store in localStorage? `textContent` will give all the text

Comment: I want the Text and the images, and i have tried all the code above using innerHTML and it gave me all the tags but i don't know how to convert them in a way that i can save in local storage

Comment: and by the way it only grabbing the first list. and i have more than one.

Comment: You can't stringify a NodeList. And don't log whole localStorage object

Comment: You need to loop over all the rows mapping each one to an object that has the properties for item, qty, price etc. Those objects would be pushed into an array that you would stringify when loop is done

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` and use `map` over it to create an array of object which will have 
`img src` and text. Then use JSON.stringify to convert this to string since local storage can only save strings.

```
var listitem = document.querySelectorAll('.each-cart-row');
   //using spread operatot to use array method on collection
    let m = [...listitem].map(function(item) {
      return {
        img: item.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src'),
        text: item.querySelector('.title').textContent.trim() // remove white space
      }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('layoutlist', JSON.stringify(m));
```

HTML

```
<div class="added-product">
      <div class="each-cart-row">
        <img class="image" src="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg">
        <h4 class="title">T-shirt</h4>
        <span class="price">$19.99</span>
        <h3>1</h3>
        <button class="removebtn">remove</button>
      </div>
      <div class="each-cart-row">
        <img class="image" src="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg">
        <h4 class="title">shirt</h4>
        <span class="price">$14.99</span>
        <h3>1</h3>
        <button class="removebtn">remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```